# Dozer creates a Map with this -> null when mapping empty Map

Tags: java, dozer

I have tried with different Map implementations, but the problem is always the same:

When I map an empty Map to another empty Map, a resulting Map contains one Entry:
this -> null.

Is it a bug? Can it be tweaked?

Comment: Why are you trying to map empty *anything*?  The use case doesn't exactly make sense to me; as I remember Dozer, it has the power to ignore empty fields.

Comment: I am not doing it intentionally. Sometimes this is the object that is build by the application based on the DB configuration. I don't what to throw isEmpty checks all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mapping an empty map to another empty map, you can set `map-null="false"`.

```
mapping map-id="Request" map-null="false"

class-a 
com.java.service.model.in.Request
/class-a
class-b
com.java.service.model.AnotherRequest
/class-b
mapping
```

Comment: The documentation says differently, that's why I didn't even try it: "You can bypass the mapping of null values. If this is specified, the dest field mapping is bypassed at runtime and the destination value setter method will not be called if the src value is null.". But I will now and let you know if it works.